# Pandas индексация с 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

При сохранение данных в Excel, индексация записей идет с 0

```
pd.DataFrame(products).to_excel(config["output_filename"], index=True)
```

Можно ли как нибудь сделать индексация с 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
import numpy as np

(pd.DataFrame(products, index=np.arange(1, len(products)+1))
   .to_excel(config["output_filename"], index=True))
```

---

несколько способов начать индекс с 1:

Пример DF:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), columns=list("abc"))

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   a   b   c
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11
```

## способ 1

```
df.index += 1
```

## способ 2

```
df = df.set_index(np.arange(1, len(df)+1))
```

## результат

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
   a   b   c
1  0   1   2
2  3   4   5
3  6   7   8
4  9  10  11
```

Comment: а np, это что? Numpy?

Comment: Спасибо большое